# Scheduling inside step using Spring-Batch

Tags: spring, batch-processing, spring-batch

Part of my job is to poll DB for a specific result status and only after that I can continue with next job's steps.

Is it recommended to stop the job's process while doing polling in one of the steps(tasklet I guess) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polling the DB for a specific result sounds like a situation where you need a scheduler.

Spring-batch assumes the scheduling of the job is done from outside it's scope.

You can use @Scheduled spring annotation if you want to keep all inside spring configuration or use an external tool like [this](http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/faq.html#schedulers).

If you have more complex situations, have a look at [Spring Batch Integration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/springBatchIntegration.html).

Comment: I already have a scheduler that running the jobs. Now I need my external scheduler service to trigger a job(which contains single  tasklet ) for polling the database ?

Comment: I think the idea is to have the job focused on only doing the actual work: query the db, if there is something to do, do it, if not just exit. And deal from outside with recalling the job. Or, query the db from outside the job instance and when work for the job has been found just create the job instance and pass the data as parameters. Doing a Thread.sleep to execute the db polling inside the execution of the job does not feel right.

Comment: Yes you right polling implemented by loop and thread.sleep feeling bad. the thing is that this polling is part of one of my job steps. if I need to extern the polling work outside than I need to split my job into 2 jobs. take all the tasks until the "polling-task" into job1 than poll the database and than start job2 (which is the rest of the tasks after the polling result)

Comment: What if I need the result from that job as param to the next job?

Comment: Have a look at [Spring Batch Integration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/springBatchIntegration.html). It should help with complex situations like the one that you seem to have.